# Solidity YUL-inline assembly, acces double mapping and updtade it

Tags: solidity, mapping, yul

Hello im stuck with yul inline assembly when i want to access a double mapping.

```
mapping(address => mapping(address => uint256)) public approval_;

function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns (bool) {
assembly {
  // doc => https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.9/internals/layout_in_storage.html
  // keccak(keccak(spender) => keccak(caller => approve slot))
  // load if user already approve this user
  let msgsender
  mstore(msgsender, caller()) // store msg.sender
  let spender_
  mstore(spender_, spender) // store spender

  let ptr := mload(0x40) // load free memory
  mstore(ptr, keccak256(spender_, 0x20)) // store hash spender
  mstore(add(ptr, 0x20), msgsender) // store msg.sender after spender hash
  mstore(add(ptr, 0x40), approval_.slot) // store approval slot after msg.sender
  let googHash := keccak256(add(ptr, 0x20), 0x40) // hash msg.sender + approval slot
  mstore(add(ptr, 0x20), googHash)
  let approveSlot := keccak256(ptr, 0x40) // hash => hash spender + hash msg.sender + approval slot
  let balanceApproved := sload(approveSlot) // load approve balance

  // store the new value
  sstore(approveSlot, add(balanceApproved, amount))
}
return true;
```

}

dont understand what im doing wrong,
thank's for ut help ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got almost everything right, only two mistakes.

First, when you're assigning `msg.sender` and `spender` to memory. Look what's happening:

```
  let msgsender                  // msgsender = 0x00
  mstore(msgsender, caller())    // memory(0x00) = caller()
  let spender_                   // spender_ = 0x00
  mstore(spender_, spender)      // memory(0x00) = spender
```

Your basically using always memory at slot 0x00 for both values, so `spender` overwrites `caller()`.

The second mistake it's that you're using as slot for `approval_[owner][spender]` the value:

```
keccak(keccak(spender) . keccak(owner . approval_.slot))
```

The correct one is the following (check the example in [the docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/internals/layout_in_storage.html#mappings-and-dynamic-arrays)):

```
keccak(spender . keccak(owner . approval_.slot))
```

Putting it all together and simplifying the structure:

```
    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint256)) public approval_;

    function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns (bool) {
      assembly {
        // compute keccak(owner . approval_.slot)
        mstore(0x00, caller())
        mstore(0x20, approval_.slot)
        let googHash := keccak256(0x00, 0x40) // hash msg.sender + approval slot
        
        // compute keccak(spender . googHash) -> this is the final slot
        // we can reuse the same memory
        mstore(0x00, spender)
        mstore(0x20, googHash)
        let approveSlot := keccak256(0x00, 0x40)
        
        // load approve balance
        let balanceApproved := sload(approveSlot)

        // store the new value
        sstore(approveSlot, add(balanceApproved, amount))
      }
      return true;
    }
```